# OriendDB Pegination in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, orientdb

What is the best way to set offset and limit for pagination in Nodejs with oriento or orientjs npm library?  I fetched some vertexs by query builder as follow:

```
db.select()
  .from('some_class')
  .limit(20)
  .all()
  .then(function (results) {
    cb(results);
  });
```

here, I can put limit but how to put offset? Either in query or query builder for pagination would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the skip(). To get the second page in your example:

```
db.select()
  .from('some_class')
  .skip(20)
  .limit(20)
  .all()
  .then(function (results) {
    cb(results);
 });
```

Comment: good solution, but this is not efficient for big cluster (~5,000,000 records).